# Python - Pendulum formula

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been posed the following question (it's a bit long-winded):

> In physics, for a pendulum with length L and initial angle A, its horizontal displacement X(T) at time T is given by the formula
>
> ```
> X(T) = L × cos(A × cos(T × √9.8/L)) - L × cos(A)
> ```
>
> Write a program which takes two lines of input; the first line is L and the second line is A. The output should be ten lines, giving the values of `X(0)`, `X(1)`, `X(2)`, ..., `X(9)`. For example, if the first line of input is `53.1` and the second line of input is `0.8`, then the first line of output is 0.0 and the second line of output is `53.1*cos(0.8*cos(1*√9.8/53.1)) - 53.1*cos(0.8) ~ 2.6689`.

I have written the following code in response to this question:

```
from math import sqrt
from math import cos
L = float(input())
A = float(input())

def X(T):
   print(L*cos(A*cos(T*sqrt(9.8/L))-L*cos(A)))

for n in range(0, 9):
   X(n)
```

...but my answers keep coming up wrong.  I'm probably missing some brackets somewhere, but I can't see where.

The output I get:

```
3.545012155898153
7.383727226708044
17.92714440725987
31.889478979714276
44.23118522394127
51.212404291669216
53.079364553814806
52.890770379027806
52.999922313121566
```

The output I'm supposed to get:

```
0.0
2.6689070487226805
9.021742145820763
14.794542557581206
15.73774678328343
11.124903835610114
4.423693604072537
0.27377375601245213
1.295906539090336
6.863309996333497
```

Comment: What answers do you get, and what answers do you expect?

Comment: Remember you can always edit the question too. So those outputs could have been added into the body of your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right, you've got misplaced parentheses. The following will fix it:

```
print(L*cos(A*cos(T*sqrt(9.8/L)))-L*cos(A))
                                ^ added    ^ removed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and to anyone else who submitted.

Answer (score 2):

you're missing brackets after the first cosine

```
L * cos(
  A * cos(
    T* sqrt(9.8/L)
  )
) - L * cos(A)
```

should be

```
 L*cos(A*cos(T*sqrt(9.8/L)))-L*cos(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

The physical formula looks like the first cos should end earlier. So one bracket at the end should go further front:

```
print(L * cos(A * cos(T * sqrt(9.8/L))) - L * cos(A))
```

A bit clearer:

```
firstCos = cos(A * cos(T * sqrt(9.8/L)))
print(L * firstCos - L * cos(A))
```